# The code stop working when I add an int attribute in a class

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Im having some problems, the code below stop working when I add an int attribute in a class, the code end when ask "wish to continue"...whitout those lines the code works well. what its wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<Humano> lista = new ArrayList<>();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String userInput;
     do {
        Humano h = new Humano(); 
        System.out.println("Name");
        h.setName(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("age");//<-----------
        h.setAge(input.nextInt());//<----------this lines causes problems
        lista.add(h);
        System.out.println("wish to continue?");
        userInput = input.nextLine();

    } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("NO"));
```

Class Human

```
public class Humano {

private String name;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: Yep that line would cause a problem... But right after that line put that `input.nextLine()` and try again.

Comment: Man! it work.....what was that?

Answer (score 2):

First answer here :)

`Scanner#nextInt()` method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus next available newline() is consumed. Best workaround for this is to add an `input.nextline()` after you use `nextInt()`, `next()` and `nextFoo()` methods.

For more answers please check this: 
[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)